# What's the best way to keep "pointers" to objects in a list?

Tags: python

I have a a list of objects. Once created, the list will not change - but the values of the attributes of the objects will change.

I need to maintain two "pointers" into the list at any one time. For example "this" and "that"

I could do this just be keeping two numerical indexes:

```
this=3
that=7
doSomething(mylist[this])
doSomethingElse(mylist[that])
this=9
doSomethingNew(mylist[this])
```

Or can I do this by using references to the objects instead?
e.g something like

```
this=mylist[3]
that=mylist[7]
doSomething(this)
doSomethingElse(that)
this=mylist[9]
doSomethingNew(this)
```

Will all operations on "this" affect the object in the list, and not a copy of it, i.e changes will be retained?

Comment: Depends on the object in the list. If it's immutable then you shouldn't have to worry, if it is mutable, you're passing references to the object, and you can't have *any* guarantees on the state of the object not changing

Comment: What kind of objects are these? If the class definition is yours, add it too.

Comment: The values of the attributes of the objects will change over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will all operations on "this" affect the object in the list, and not a copy of it, i.e changes will be retained?

Yes.  The list just contains references on the same objects.

> what's the best way to keep "pointers" to objects in a list?

You've mentioned "*Once created, the list will not change*", so many of the arguments about whether it's better to maintain indices to the list, or just the objects themselves, are irrelevant here.

So what do you do with the indices?

- If you *only* use the indices in order to access the objects (via `list.__getitem__`), then you may as well just maintain references on those objects directly.
- If you care about the value of the indices, e.g. the distance between this pair of items in the list, or whether either is at the start/end/middle of the list, then use integers.

A custom class might be a good choice here, but you'll have to post more code and describe the use case to get a solid recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

So long as you don't reallocate the objects themselves, either method will work.  Are these objects a mutable type?

Reallocation also depends on how your **doSomething** methods work.

I strongly recommend that you do the research you should have done before posting: code up a trivial version of what you want to do, try it each way, and see whether each version has the functionality you need.

---

If both of them work, then you need to decide based on software design issues: Is it easy to read?  Is it fast?  Is it easy to maintain?  Is it easy for others to understand?

For instance, several times, I have chosen a slower algorithm (e.g. bubble sort instead of a pointer-based merge sort) because the list would never grow large enough for the time difference to matter, and a bubble sort is something *any* software head in my group, now or in the future, could understand and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Yes, all changes to `this` and `that` will show up in the list. This is because of the way variable assignment works in Python - (variable) names are references to values.

Refer to this article on how variable assignment works in python: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Useful snippet from the article: "a Python assignment statement associates a symbolic name on the left-hand side with a value on the right-hand side. In Python, we say that names refer to values, or a name is a reference to a value ... If you have list elements referring to other mutable values, like sub-lists, it's important to remember that the list elements are just references to values."

Another useful resource to understand how variables and assignment work in Python: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables